# Applying QPE on a large matrix on amazon-braket

Tags: programming, hamiltonian-simulation, quantum-phase-estimation, amazon-braket

I'm running a QPE algorithm on the amazon-braket but it can only apply on a 2*2 or 4*4 matrix, when I want to expand it into a 5*5 or more, it will come an error. As I know, there is no theoretical limitation on the size of matrix QPE can solve.

Here is the main part of the code:

```
def get_qpe_phases(measurement_counts, precision_qubits, items_to_keep=1):
    bitstrings_precision_register = [
        substring(key, precision_qubits) for key in measurement_counts.keys()
    ]
    bitstrings_precision_register_set = set(bitstrings_precision_register)
    bitstrings_precision_register_list = list(bitstrings_precision_register_set)
    precision_results_dic = {key: 0 for key in bitstrings_precision_register_list}

    for key in measurement_counts.keys():
        counts = measurement_counts[key]
        count_key = substring(key, precision_qubits)
        precision_results_dic[count_key] += counts

    c = Counter(precision_results_dic)
    topmost = c.most_common(items_to_keep)
    phases_decimal = [binaryToDecimal(item[0]) for item in topmost]

    return phases_decimal, precision_results_dic


def run_qpe(
    unitary,
    precision_qubits,
    query_qubits,
    query_circuit,
    items_to_keep=1,
    shots=1000
):
    circ = query_circuit
    circ.qpe(precision_qubits, query_qubits, unitary, control_unitary=False)

    # Add desired results_types
    
    number_precision_qubits = len(precision_qubits)
    
    num_qubits = len(precision_qubits)
    circ.probability(np.array(precision_qubits))
    device = LocalSimulator()
    task=device.run(circ,shots=shots)
    result=task.result()
    metadata = result.task_metadata

    probs_values = result.values[0]
    measurements = result.measurements
    measured_qubits = result.measured_qubits
    measurement_counts = result.measurement_counts
    measurement_probabilities = result.measurement_probabilities
    format_bitstring = "{0:0" + str(num_qubits) + "b}"
    bitstring_keys = [format_bitstring.format(ii) for ii in range(2 ** num_qubits)]


    phases_decimal, precision_results_dic = get_qpe_phases(
        measurement_counts, precision_qubits, items_to_keep
    )
    
    print('\nPhases:',phases_decimal)
    
    eigenvalues = [np.exp(2 * np.pi * 1j * phase) for phase in phases_decimal]

    # aggregate results
    out = {
        "circuit": circ,
        "task_metadata": metadata,
        "measurements": measurements,
        "measured_qubits": measured_qubits,
        "measurement_counts": measurement_counts,
        "measurement_probabilities": measurement_probabilities,
        "probs_values": probs_values,
        "bitstring_keys": bitstring_keys,
        "precision_results_dic": precision_results_dic,
        "phases_decimal": phases_decimal,
        "eigenvalues": eigenvalues,
    }

    return out
```

And when it comes to a 6*6 matrix,

```
from scipy.stats import unitary_group
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(seed=3000)

unitary1 = unitary_group.rvs(6)
result = estimate_phase(4,unitary1,5,printcir=False)
```

the error report is like:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-4eae0beac402> in <module>
      4 
      5 unitary = unitary_group.rvs(6)
----> 6 result = estimate_phase(4,unitary,5,printcir=False)

<ipython-input-9-30dffae9e6c6> in estimate_phase(n, unitary, runit, shots, printcir)
     15     query = Circuit().h(query_qubits)
     16 
---> 17     result = run_qpe(unitary, precision_qubits, query_qubits, query, items_to_keep=elen, shots = shots)
     18     qeigvals= postprocess_qpe_results(result,printcir)
     19 

<ipython-input-6-1875e0e5a610> in run_qpe(unitary, precision_qubits, query_qubits, query_circuit, items_to_keep, shots)
     92 ):
     93     circ = query_circuit
---> 94     circ.qpe(precision_qubits, query_qubits, unitary, control_unitary=False)
     95 
     96     # Add desired results_types

~/anaconda3/envs/Braket/lib/python3.7/site-packages/braket/circuits/circuit.py in method_from_subroutine(self, *args, **kwargs)
     75 
     76         def method_from_subroutine(self, *args, **kwargs) -> SubroutineReturn:
---> 77             return self.add(func, *args, **kwargs)
     78 
     79         function_name = func.__name__

~/anaconda3/envs/Braket/lib/python3.7/site-packages/braket/circuits/circuit.py in add(self, addable, *args, **kwargs)
    495                 self.add_circuit(item, *args, **kwargs)
    496             elif callable(item):
--> 497                 self.add(item(*args, **kwargs))
    498             else:
    499                 raise TypeError(f"Cannot add a '{type(item)}' to a Circuit")

<ipython-input-6-1875e0e5a610> in qpe(precision_qubits, query_qubits, unitary, control_unitary)
     39         else:
     40             for _ in range(2 ** power):
---> 41                 qpe_circ.controlled_unitary(qubit, query_qubits, unitary)
     42     qpe_circ.inverse_qft(precision_qubits)
     43 

~/anaconda3/envs/Braket/lib/python3.7/site-packages/braket/circuits/circuit.py in method_from_subroutine(self, *args, **kwargs)
     75 
     76         def method_from_subroutine(self, *args, **kwargs) -> SubroutineReturn:
---> 77             return self.add(func, *args, **kwargs)
     78 
     79         function_name = func.__name__

~/anaconda3/envs/Braket/lib/python3.7/site-packages/braket/circuits/circuit.py in add(self, addable, *args, **kwargs)
    495                 self.add_circuit(item, *args, **kwargs)
    496             elif callable(item):
--> 497                 self.add(item(*args, **kwargs))
    498             else:
    499                 raise TypeError(f"Cannot add a '{type(item)}' to a Circuit")

<ipython-input-6-1875e0e5a610> in controlled_unitary(control, target_qubits, unitary)
     21     targets = [control] + target_qubits
     22 
---> 23     circ.unitary(matrix=controlled_matrix, targets=targets)
     24 
     25     return circ

~/anaconda3/envs/Braket/lib/python3.7/site-packages/braket/circuits/circuit.py in method_from_subroutine(self, *args, **kwargs)
     75 
     76         def method_from_subroutine(self, *args, **kwargs) -> SubroutineReturn:
---> 77             return self.add(func, *args, **kwargs)
     78 
     79         function_name = func.__name__

~/anaconda3/envs/Braket/lib/python3.7/site-packages/braket/circuits/circuit.py in add(self, addable, *args, **kwargs)
    495                 self.add_circuit(item, *args, **kwargs)
    496             elif callable(item):
--> 497                 self.add(item(*args, **kwargs))
    498             else:
    499                 raise TypeError(f"Cannot add a '{type(item)}' to a Circuit")

~/anaconda3/envs/Braket/lib/python3.7/site-packages/braket/circuits/gates.py in unitary(targets, matrix, display_name)
   1339         """
   1340         if 2 ** len(targets) != matrix.shape[0]:
-> 1341             raise ValueError("Dimensions of the supplied unitary are incompatible with the targets")
   1342 
   1343         return Instruction(Gate.Unitary(matrix, display_name), target=targets)

ValueError: Dimensions of the supplied unitary are incompatible with the targets
```

So I'm wondering if it's the packages' problem or the program problem or any other had met the similar problem as I?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because there's a mismatch between the dimensions of the unitary matrix and the qubits it's acting on (for example, a 16 x 16 matrix acting on 5 qubits). I'm suspecting there's a bug somewhere in `qpe`; what are the dimensions of the unitary and the number of qubits?